# Using ActiveRecord (Ruby) how to construct an all 'in use' query?

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, join, count

I have a Tag class that is associated with a bunch of other classs via `has_and_belongs_to_many` and am looking for a simple way to return only the collection of tags that are 'in use'.

I'm trying this with a `scope` as follows

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :widgets

  # it's in_use if users.count > 0 || widgets.count > 0
  scope :in_use, joins(:users).where('users.count > 0').merge(joins(:widgets).where("widgets.count > 0"))
end
```

However I get this error - `SQLException: no such column: users.count`

How best to achieve my desired oucome such that I can just get all tags that are in use via `Tag.in_use`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up solving this as follows.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :widgets

  def self.in_use
    return find_by_sql('select tags.* from tags 
      inner join tags_users on tags.id = tags_users.tag_id 
      inner join users on tags_users.user_id = users.id 
      union select tags.* from tags 
      inner join tags_widgets on tags.id = tags_widgets.tag_id 
      inner join widgets on tags_widgets.widget_id = widgets.id')
  end

end
```

as putting the `find_by_sql` clause into a named `scope` doesn't actually work (see comment on Gordon Wilson's answer).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do this with activerecord helpers.  But you can do this with raw sql.  If your join tables are called `tags_users` and `tags_widgets`, then something like this will work:

```
scope :in_use, find_by_sql('select * from tags 
    inner join tags_users on tags.id = tags_users.tag_id 
    inner join users on tags_users.user_id = users.id 
    union select * from tags 
    inner join tags_widgets on tags.id = tags_widgets.tag_id 
    inner join widgets on tags_widgets.widget_id = widgets.id')
```

Comment: Thanks that's a help but I get the weird situation now where `Tag.in_use.count` is always `0` but if I just go `Tag.find_by_sql(…).count` I get an actual result. I suppose I could just nix the `scope` idea and wrap the `find_by_sql` into a class method. Will keep experimenting however. There seems to be an issue with using `find_by_sql` within a `scope`.